# Double integral over ellipse approach

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to calculate the following integral $\iint_D x^2y^4dxdy$ over $D=\{(x,y)\in (0,\infty)^2: 9x^2+4y^2<36\}$. What I'd like to do is first set $x^2=\frac{1}{9}w^2, y^2=\frac{1}{4}z^2$. Thus the problem becomes to integrate $\iint_{D'} \frac{1}{9\cdot 16}w^2z^4 dwdz$ with $D'=\{(w,z) \in (0,\infty)^2: w^2+z^2<36\}$. Now I can apply the variable exchange in polar coordinates and solve the problem with angle going from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $r\in(0,6)$. However, the approach seems not to be correct as I don't obtain the correct answer. There is clearly a more direct variable exchange withoud passing by my passage from $D$ to $D'$, but I'd like to understand why this approach doesn't hold. If someone could tell where the problem is, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You forgot about the Jacobian so your integral is off by a constant. Also, it's simpler to write the substitution as $x=w/3, y=z/2$.

Comment: Oh yes of course thank you I forgot to multiply by 1/6